# lucene, efficient way to get offsets of a set of terms in documents

Tags: lucene

Suppose I have indexed a set of documents and now I am given a set of terms that I known are generated by the indexing process. I would like to get the occurrence of each of these terms, i.e., which document, what offsets. I have done this using, for each term, one postingnums that let me to iterate through the set of documents a term appear in; then within each document, one postingenums to get document vector that contains the offset information of that term in that document.

But this is not very efficient as there is loop inside loop and can go quite slow. The code is below. Any suggestions if this can be done in a better way?

The field schema:

```
<field name="terms" type="token_ngram" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="false" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true"/>
```

Code:

```
IndexReader indexReader = ...//init an index reader
Set<String> termSet = .... //set containing e.g., 10000 terms.
for(String term: termSet){
    //get a postingenum used to iterate through docs containing the term
    //this "postings" does not have valid offset information (see comment below)
    PostingsEnum postings =
            MultiFields.getTermDocsEnum(indexReader, "terms", new BytesRef(term.getBytes()));
    /*I also tried: 
     *PostingsEnum postings =
     *       MultiFields.getTermDocsEnum(indexReader, "terms", new BytesRef(term.getBytes()), PostingsEnum.OFFSETS);
     * But the resulting "postings" object also does not contain valid offset info (always -1)
     */

    //now go through each document
    int docId = postings.nextDoc();
    while (docId != PostingsEnum.NO_MORE_DOCS) {
        //get the term vector for that document.
        TermsEnum it = indexReader.getTermVector(docId, ngramInfoFieldname).iterator();
        //find the term of interest
        it.seekExact(new BytesRef(term.getBytes()));
        //get its posting info. this will contain offset info
        PostingsEnum postingsInDoc = it.postings(null, PostingsEnum.OFFSETS);

        //From below, Line A to Line B if I replace "postingsInDoc" with "postings", method "posting.startOffset()" and "endoffset()" always returns -1; 
        postingsInDoc.nextDoc(); //line A

        int totalFreq = postingsInDoc.freq();
        for (int i = 0; i < totalFreq; i++) {
            postingsInDoc.nextPosition();
            System.out.println(postingsInDoc.startOffset(), postingsInDoc.endOffset());
        }        //Line B     

        docId=postings.nextDoc();
    }
}
```